# Aligning checkboxes in the header and column properly

Tags: c#, asp.net

I just can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. I want checkboxes in the first column display in one direct line under my header with checkbox. Code sample:

```
 <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                    GridLines="None" AllowSorting="True"
                    AllowPaging="True" PageSize="20" Width="100%" >
                     <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" Wrap="False" />
                <Columns>
                 <asp:TemplateField>
                       <HeaderTemplate>
                            <input ID="SelectAllEvs" runat="server" type="checkbox" />                                
                       </HeaderTemplate>                       
                       <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:CheckBox ID="EventSelector" runat="server" />                                  
                       </ItemTemplate>    
                        <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" />                                                                   
                   </asp:TemplateField>                       
                       <asp:BoundField DataField="EventDate" 
                            ...
                        <ItemStyle Wrap="False" />
                       </asp:BoundField>
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="Subject" 
                            ...                         
                       </asp:BoundField>
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="Body" 
                            ...
                       </asp:BoundField>                         
                </Columns>                    
    </asp:GridView>
```

And image sample of what i have in result is attached.
Thanx for any help.[image]

Answer (score 0):

Remove `<ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" />` for checkbox. and give a fix width to that column:

```
 <RowStyle Width="150px"/>
```

Comment: Sorry, but this just doesn't help as well

Answer (score 0):

Try this code :

```
<Columns>
             <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Checkbox">                             
                   <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:CheckBox ID="EventSelector" runat="server" />                                  
                   </ItemTemplate>    
                    <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" />                                                                   
               </asp:TemplateField>                                                                     
</Columns>
```

Comment: This code will assigns new header text as Checkbox very easily..If solution works please marks it as correct answer so it can become helpful to other.

Comment: It surely doeas what you've stated but I don't need a text "checkbox" in the header. I need a checkbox control aligned the same as other checkboxes in the column.